# Chrome Web Store does not accept localization message file in hindi

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have developed an extension for Google Chrome, and I now localizing it to several languages. I have successfully localized it to many languages that use different alphabets (e.g. Russian, Hebrew, ...), but today I tried to upload to the web store a new version of the extension containing Hindi localization, and I got the following error:

```
An error occurred: Failed to process your item.

_locales/hi/messages.json:1:1: a object must begin with '{'.
```

The messages.json file for Hindi (hi) contains the following:

```
{
  "appName": {
    "message": "Mind the Word",
    "description": "The title of the application, displayed in the web store."
  },
  "appDesc": {
    "message": "इंटरनेट सर्फिंग करते समय भाषा सीखें|",
    "description": "The description of the application, displayed in the web store."
  }
}
```

I suspect it is an encoding issue. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had accidentally changed the encoding of the messages.json file to UTF-16. When I changed the encoding back to UTF-8, I was able to upload the new version of the extension to the web store.